# Optimizing away method calls in VS2010 c++ (multithreaded)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

```
//A count protected internally by a Mutex
class AtomicCount
{
public:
  AtomicCount();
  ~AtomicCount();
  int value() const;
  void increment();
private:
  HANDLE hMutex;
  int count;
};

AtomicCount myCount;
void loop_until_set() {
  while(!myCount.value())
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Say we call loop_until_set() in one thread, where we are waiting for another thread to do myCount.increment(). Is there ever a danger that myCount.value() is optimized away in such a way that it could never read the updated value when another thread calls myCount.increment()?

Comment: without synchronization you have a race condition.

Comment: Need to see the code for `value()` to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate thoroughly before using `volatile` (you may still have race conditions; some people think using volatile is always an oversimplistic solution) but you absolutely need that on the `count` member. Otherwise this simple scenario will cause calls to value() to get optimized away (in vc2010)

```
inline void _sleep(int len) { for(int i=0;i<len;i++) { volatile int j=i; }; }
#define Sleep(x) _sleep(x)
```

This may be contrived, but it is revealing of the main circumstances in which the re-read of the variable would be required: when an external function that can't be inlined is called, the compiler doesn't know what may have happened to the contents of myCount while the execution was far away.